# Open or activate an application in specific shortcut

Tags: applications, shortcut, keybindings

I'd like to bind certain keyboard shortcuts to certain applications, and have it open and be visible when it is pressed.

For example, I want to have the [Things](https://culturedcode.com) app open (if not already open) and be focused to front, when pressing `Cmd+Ctrl+H`.

Can I do this natively on macOS? Or does it require a special application?

At the moment, I press `Cmd+Tab` repeatedly but this is not idea, as I'd like to bind shortcuts for a bunch of frequently-accessed apps.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [single key keyboard shortcut run-or-raise applications](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/265916/single-key-keyboard-shortcut-run-or-raise-applications)

Comment: This is another of those scenarios i'd consider using Spaces instead of Cmd/Tab - See https://superuser.com/a/1187552/347380 and https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/179403/85275 It's also considerably easier to set up & requires no 3rd party or scripting solution, it just works.